# Printing random even value between two values using inheritance

Tags: java, class, inheritance, random

I am trying to print a list of random even numbers (5 times) using a bounds. Example being from 0 to 30 (including both those numbers). This is what I have so far (this is in its own class):

```
public int nextEven(int h){
        int n = rand.nextEven(h) % 2;
        return n;
        }
```

This is where it would print from my main method:

```
System.out.println("Random Even:");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        System.out.println(rand.nextEven(30));
    }
```

When I run the program it gives me an error and I am not quite sure how to solve this. This is an example of the desired output of even numbers from 0 to 30:

4
26
12
10
20

Comment: You have an infinite recursion that usually leads to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Where does inheritance come into this?

Comment: Is `rand` a reference to the class that contains your methods? If so, you have a infinite recursion as PM 77-1 said.

Comment: yeah I was getting the stack overflow error but im not sure how to go around it or how to not make it an infinite recursion

Comment: None of our answers have dealt with the inheritance part of the question. @SeanLynch how does inheritance need to come into this?

Comment: I have actually realized that I don't need to do that I was misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't clear why taking the remainder of `2` would yield an even number. Instead, generate a number in the range `0` to `h / 2` and then multiply the result of that by `2`. Like,

```
public int nextEven(int h){
    int n = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1 + (h / 2)); // 0 to (h / 2) inclusive
    return n * 2; // n * 2 is even (or zero).
}
```

Comment: OP wants/thinks `nextEven(30)` should be an even number *"from 0 to 30 (including both those numbers)"*. You should address that in the answer too.

Comment: @Andreas I missed the including. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is rand? Is it the Random class or an instance of your own class?
Since you want to do something with inheritance I guess you want to overwrite a method, but if rand is an instance of the java Random class this won't work.

The error probably comes from recursively calling nextEven method forever.

If you could clarify what exactly you want to do?

Comment: Rand is an instance of my own class

Answer (score 0):

The mod operator `%` will give you the remainder of the first value divided by the second.

```
value % 2
```

... will return 0 if `value` is even, or 1 if `value` is odd.

Since `rand` is a reference to an instance of the class containing your code, you have an infinite recursion. What you really need is something like:

```
public int nextEven(int h){
    int evenRandomValue;
    do {
        evenRandomValue = (int)(Math.random() * (h + 1));
    } while(evenRandomValue % 2 == 1);

    return evenRandomValue;
}
```

Comment: Although your answer is correct, looping to skip odd numbers is bad for performance, considering that you can simply ask for numbers in half the range and multiply by 2 to get even-only numbers.

Comment: Solve first. Optimise later. But I do like your optimisation.

Answer (score 0):

I see at least two solutions.

The first one supposes that `random + 1 = random`. I mean, that if you add or subtract a random number you still get a valid random number. That's why you can use `Random` class to generate a value in the desired period and then add or subtract one it the number is odd.

The second approach is just to generate an array of even values for the desired period. Then take a random value from this array.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quite explicit way to achieve this using streams:

```
List<Integer> myRandomInts = Random.ints(lower, upper + 1)
    .filter(i -> i % 2 == 0)
    .limit(5).boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This can be read as 'generate an infinite stream of random numbers between given bounds, filter out odds, take the first 5, turn into `Integer` objects and then collect into a list.